# Print result in table after matching queries

Tags: php

I am trying to make table with two headers filled with information from db.

I have to check if user has a record in table for specific day in a month.

If user has a record in table (checked_user) then I should print "yes" in date column and in user row if user does not have entry for that date I should print "no".

One header will contain days of chosen month while another will print user names.

I have two tables in database (users and checked_users).

Users table contains user data, while checked_users contains if user is checked for specific date.

Then I have tab

Table user:

```
UposlenikID |UposlenikImePrezime | UposlenikStatus

  1           User1                     0
  2           User2                     0
  3           User3                     0
```

Table checked_user:

```
Id | UposlenikID  | Vrijeme            | Command

1      4           2016-11-30 14:28:02  Odjava

2     10           2016-11-30 14:30:54  Odjava

3      3           2016-12-01 09:17:00  Prijava

4      4           2016-12-01 09:17:03  Prijava

12  4   2016-12-01 09:17:18     Odjava
```

First I create Query to get all users from table

```
$users = "SELECT UposlenikID, UposlenikImePrezime FROM uposlenici WHERE UposlenikStatus = 0";

$q = $conn->query($users);
```

Then I create table:

```
$date = '2016-11-01';
$end = '2016-11-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); //get end date of month

<table border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>
             <?php 
               while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
                $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
                $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
                $day_month = date('m', strtotime($date));
                $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day",       strtotime($date)));
                echo "<td>$day_name <br/> $day_num | $day_month</td>";
                } ?>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php 
        $i=1;
        while($r=$q->fetch()) {  
       ?>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <?php  echo $i++;  ?>
           </td>
           <td>
              <?=$r['UposlenikImePrezime']; ?>
           </td>    
           <td>

           </td>

       </tr>
     <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
```

Output table should look like table below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQL Query ( Case & Join ) ,

```
 SELECT user.UposlenikID , user.UposlenikImePrezime,checked_user.Vrijeme,
 CASE WHEN user.UposlenikID=checked_user.UposlenikID  THEN 'yes'
            ELSE 'No' END AS is_checked
 FROM user 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN checked_user
  ON (user.UposlenikID=checked_user.UposlenikID) ;
```

get the Query Result as below

```
UposlenikID : UposlenikImePrezime : Vrijeme               : is_checked

1           | user1               | NULL                   | No
2           | user2               | NULL                   | No
3           | user3               | 2016-12-01 09:17:00    | Yes
```

and then format the result to table using php .

Comment: Did you get my point? Using Case and join query , will get the result and then format whatever you want.is a easy way?What you expected without sqlQuery ?